# My last two elif/else statement wont execute, and I cant find out why?

Tags: python

Im having a rather simple problem with a my last  elif and else statements in the following code... they simply wont execute. Im a big noob with python so it can be very likely its a simple mistake :/
the console dosnt show any syntax error or anything... it executes the code, but with the wrong result

```
            starthandvalue = 0

            if splitfirstcard[0] == splitsecondcard[0]:
                ispar = True
                
                if (splitfirstcard[0] and splitsecondcard[0] == 'A') or (splitfirstcard[0] and splitsecondcard[0]== 'K') or (splitfirstcard[0] and splitsecondcard[0] == 'Q'):
                    starthandvalue =+83
                    
                elif (splitfirstcard[0] and splitsecondcard[0] == 'J') or (splitfirstcard[0] and splitsecondcard[0] == '10') or (splitfirstcard[0] and splitsecondcard[0] == '9'):
                    starthandvalue =+75

                elif (splitfirstcard[0] and splitsecondcard[0] == '8') or (splitfirstcard[0] and splitsecondcard[0] == '7') or (splitfirstcard[0] and splitsecondcard[0] == '6') or (splitfirstcard[0] and splitsecondcard[0] == '5'):
                    starthandvalue ==+62

                else:
                    starthandvalue ==+55
```

OUTPUT

````
['Q', 's'] ['Q', 'h']
 Hand value: about 83%
['9', 's'] ['9', 'h']
 Hand value: about 75%
['6', 's'] ['6', 'h']
 Hand value: about 0%  <--- this should be 62
['2', 's'] ['2', 'h']
 Hand value: about 0%  <--- this should be 55
['3', 's'] ['3', 'd']
 Hand value: about 0%  <--- this should be 55
['K', 's'] ['K', 'd']
 Hand value: about 83%
```
````

Comment: im trying to check if both cards are 'A'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the operators such as `=+` and `==+` to `+=`

Answer (score 2):

Quick glance, `splitfirstcard[0] and splitsecondcard[0] == '5'` doesn't mean what you think. These statements should be `splitfirstcard[0] == 5 and splitsecondcard[0] == '5'`

Example:

```
t1 = 'a'
t2 = 'b'
t1 and t2 == 'b'
Out: True

t1 == 'b' and t2 == 'b'
Out: False
```